# App for grabbing data from some APIs (electricity usage & solar panel production) & putting them into a DB

Tags: rust

I made an app for my internal use that collects some metrics & puts them into a DB. I'd be happy if someone could comment on my code, commenting, design choices and so. I hope I did enough commenting, aside from the code quality - the app run pretty well! I apologize for only including the initial commit - it's a small app, my other apps, which are unfortunately private, have their commits (I hope) separated better. Thank you nice people of Code Review!

main.rs (Initial impression!)

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    dotenv::dotenv()?;

    let solax = SolaxApi::init(&env::var("TOKEN_ID").unwrap(), &env::var("SITE_ID").unwrap());

    let power = solax.get_inverter_power().await?;

    let mut db = Db::init(&env::var("MYSQL_DB_URL").unwrap())?;

    db.write_inverter_power(&power)?;

    let wa = WattAnalyticsApi::init(
        &env::var("WA_USERNAME").unwrap(), 
        &env::var("WA_PASSWORD").unwrap()
    ).await?;

    let data = wa
        .get_power_meter_data(
            &env::var("METER_ID").unwrap(), 
            1, 
            1, 
            Local::now(), 
            Local::now().checked_add_signed(Duration::milliseconds(10000)).unwrap() // smaller from-to differences give off just an empty array
        )
        .await?
        .power_data;

    db.write_home_power_usage(data.first().unwrap())?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[The GitHub repository](https://github.com/timleg002/solarpanelreq)

Comment: Don't `unwrap`, use `expect` would be my first advise ;) Also, instead of using `env::var` all over the please, use a crate like [dotenvy](https://crates.io/crates/dotenvy) to help with environment configuration

Comment: I refactored the codebase a bit to use the try operator on environment variables, since I found out that it gives an Result instead of an Option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good! Here are my suggestions for improving the structure to make it a bit easier to maintain and extend:

---

As far as I can tell `dotenv` is not actively maintained so it might be better to switch to its fork [dotenvy](https://crates.io/crates/dotenvy)

---

Do not call `Local::now()` twice as time will pass between the two calls and your range will be inconsistent or even incorrect if the second call is delayed too much.

```rust
let from = Local::now();
let to = from.checked_add_signed(Duration::milliseconds(10000))?;
```

---

Extract the names of the environmental variables and magic numbers into `const`s so that they are easier to find and update when needed.

```rust
const TOKEN_ID: &str = "TOKEN_ID";
const SITE_ID: &str = "SITE_ID";
const WA_USERNAME: &str = "WA_USERNAME";
const WA_PASSWORD: &str = "WA_PASSWORD";
const MYSQL_DB_URL: &str = "MYSQL_DB_URL";
const METER_ID: &str = "METER_ID";
const DELAY: i64 = 10_000;
```

---

Separate the creation and initialization of objects from their usage to increase readability.

```rust
struct PowerApp {
    solax_api: SolaxApi,
    watt_api: WattAnalyticsApi,
    db: Db,
}

impl PowerApp {
    pub async fn new(
        solax_token_id: String,
        solax_site_id: String,
        watt_api_username: String,
        watt_api_password: String,
        db_url: String,
    ) -> Result<Self> {
        let solax_api = SolaxApi::init(&solax_token_id, &solax_site_id);
        let watt_api = WattAnalyticsApi::init(&watt_api_username, &watt_api_password).await?;
        let db = Db::init(&db_url)?;
        Ok(Self {
            solax_api,
            watt_api,
            db,
        })
    }

    pub async fn execute(&mut self, meter_id: u32, depth: u32, num_of_readings: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let power = self.solax_api.get_inverter_power().await?;
        self.db.write_inverter_power(power)?;

        let from = Local::now();
        let to = from.checked_add_signed(Duration::milliseconds(DELAY))?;

        let data = self
            .watt_api
            .get_power_meter_data(
                meter_id,
                depth,
                num_of_readings,
                from,
                to,
            )
            .await?.power_data;

        self.db.write_home_power_usage(data.first()?)
    }
}
```

---

User builder pattern to create the `PowerApp`. This gives you the flexibility to use different methods for initializing the `PowerApp`, for example with command line arguments, while still defaulting to reading them from environmental variables if nothing else is provided.

```rust
struct PowerAppBuilder {
    solax_token_id: Option<String>,
    solax_site_id: Option<String>,
    watt_api_username: Option<String>,
    watt_api_password: Option<String>,
    db_url: Option<String>,
}

impl PowerAppBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            solax_token_id: None,
            solax_site_id: None,
            watt_api_username: None,
            watt_api_password: None,
            db_url: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn solax_token_id(&mut self, solax_token_id: String) {
        self.solax_token_id = Some(solax_token_id)
    }
    pub fn solax_site_id(&mut self, solax_site_id: String) {
        self.solax_site_id = Some(solax_site_id)
    }
    pub fn watt_api_username(&mut self, watt_api_username: String) {
        self.watt_api_username = Some(watt_api_username)
    }
    pub fn watt_api_password(&mut self, watt_api_password: String) {
        self.watt_api_password = Some(watt_api_password)
    }
    pub fn db_url(&mut self, db_url: String) {
        self.db_url = Some(db_url)
    }

    pub async fn build(self) -> Result<PowerApp> {
        PowerApp::new(
            self.solax_token_id.unwrap_or(env::var(TOKEN_ID)?),
            self.solax_site_id.unwrap_or(env::var(SITE_ID)?),
            self.watt_api_username.unwrap_or(env::var(WA_USERNAME)?),
            self.watt_api_password.unwrap_or(env::var(WA_PASSWORD)?),
            self.db_url.unwrap_or(env::var(MYSQL_DB_URL)?),
        )
            .await
    }
}
```

---

Final Code:

```rust
const TOKEN_ID: &str = "TOKEN_ID";
const SITE_ID: &str = "SITE_ID";
const WA_USERNAME: &str = "WA_USERNAME";
const WA_PASSWORD: &str = "WA_PASSWORD";
const MYSQL_DB_URL: &str = "MYSQL_DB_URL";
const METER_ID: &str = "METER_ID";
const DELAY: i64 = 10_000;

struct PowerAppBuilder {
    solax_token_id: Option<String>,
    solax_site_id: Option<String>,
    watt_api_username: Option<String>,
    watt_api_password: Option<String>,
    db_url: Option<String>,
}

impl PowerAppBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            solax_token_id: None,
            solax_site_id: None,
            watt_api_username: None,
            watt_api_password: None,
            db_url: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn solax_token_id(&mut self, solax_token_id: String) {
        self.solax_token_id = Some(solax_token_id)
    }
    pub fn solax_site_id(&mut self, solax_site_id: String) {
        self.solax_site_id = Some(solax_site_id)
    }
    pub fn watt_api_username(&mut self, watt_api_username: String) {
        self.watt_api_username = Some(watt_api_username)
    }
    pub fn watt_api_password(&mut self, watt_api_password: String) {
        self.watt_api_password = Some(watt_api_password)
    }
    pub fn db_url(&mut self, db_url: String) {
        self.db_url = Some(db_url)
    }

    pub async fn build(self) -> Result<PowerApp> {
        PowerApp::new(
            self.solax_token_id.unwrap_or(env::var(TOKEN_ID)?),
            self.solax_site_id.unwrap_or(env::var(SITE_ID)?),
            self.watt_api_username.unwrap_or(env::var(WA_USERNAME)?),
            self.watt_api_password.unwrap_or(env::var(WA_PASSWORD)?),
            self.db_url.unwrap_or(env::var(MYSQL_DB_URL)?),
        )
            .await
    }
}

struct PowerApp {
    solax_api: SolaxApi,
    watt_api: WattAnalyticsApi,
    db: Db,
}

impl PowerApp {
    pub async fn new(
        solax_token_id: String,
        solax_site_id: String,
        watt_api_username: String,
        watt_api_password: String,
        db_url: String,
    ) -> Result<Self> {
        let solax_api = SolaxApi::init(&solax_token_id, &solax_site_id);
        let watt_api = WattAnalyticsApi::init(&watt_api_username, &watt_api_password).await?;
        let db = Db::init(&db_url)?;
        Ok(Self {
            solax_api,
            watt_api,
            db,
        })
    }

    pub async fn execute(&mut self, meter_id: u32, depth: u32, num_of_readings: u32) -> Result<()> {
        let power = self.solax_api.get_inverter_power().await?;
        self.db.write_inverter_power(power)?;

        let from = Local::now();
        let to = from.checked_add_signed(Duration::milliseconds(DELAY)).some;

        let data = self
            .watt_api
            .get_power_meter_data(
                meter_id,
                depth,
                num_of_readings,
                from,
                to,
            )
            .await?.power_data;

        self.db.write_home_power_usage(data.first().unwrap())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    dotenvy::dotenv()?;
    let mut app = PowerAppBuilder::new().build().await?;
    app.execute(env::var(METER_ID)?).await
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice code review! I thought about doing constants for the env vars, but then I realized I load them in only one place. The builder pattern is certainly interesting! The time thingy is kind of weird, thank you for your solution, but it turns out the approach didn't even work, I switched it up to first loading the current time minus the delay as the from time, then loading the current time again as the to time, thus any unexpected delays will not affect the data loading.

Comment: Keep in mind that even with your new approach to specifying the time window you may still have inconsistent ranges between executions due to getting the current time twice. This may or may not cause a problem in your case but in general is not considered a good practice and can cause other issues down the line, for example flaky unit tests.